# Convert a non-escaping closure to an escaping one or the other way

Tags: swift, closures

I'm creating a template pattern to easily switch between Nimble And XCTAssert for my Unit Tests.

So I have a protocol

```
protocol Assertable {
  func notNil(_ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> Any?, file: StaticString, line: UInt)
}
```

XCTAssert implementation of not nil is like so:

`func XCTAssertNotNil(_ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> Any?, _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = default, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line)`

and Nimber's is:

`func expect<T>(_ expression: @autoclosure @escaping () throws -> T?, file: FileString = #file, line: UInt = #line) -> Expectation<T>`

Basically the only difference is that one is escaping and not the other one.

My problem is that if I declare my templates with @escaping, XCTAssertNotNil(expression) won't work anymore because an escaped closure can never be considered as `nil` so XCTAssertNotNil will always be true and XCTAssertNil will always be false.

And if I delcare my templates non-escaping, then Nimble won't be happy because it requires escaped closures.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to convert an non escaping to an escaping closure is to perform the block.

```
func XCTAssertNotNil(_ expression: @autoclosure () throws -> Any?) {
    do {
        let performed = try expression()

        expect(performed)
    } catch {
        expect({ throw error })
    }
}
```

Vice versa should be not an problem:

```
func expect<T>(_ expression: @autoclosure @escaping () throws -> T?) {
    XCTAssertNotNil(expression)
}
```